# How do I save the values that the user enters in this indefinite loop to be used later to find the largest and smallest value?

Tags: python

Question= Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers.

So basically I have to write a program as stated above.
EDIT: Im done with this question but would like to edit a try and except clause that would show an error if I were to enter a string instead of an integer. when I run the code the error message comes out but the string still gets added to the numberlist :(

```
    def findlargest():
    largest= None
    for value in numberlist:
        if largest is None:
            largest= value
        elif value> largest:
            largest= value

    print "The largest value is", largest

def findsmallest():
    smallest=None
    for value in numberlist:
        if smallest is None:
            smallest= value
        elif value<smallest:
            smallest= value
    print "The smallest value is: ", smallest





numberlist=[]
while True:
    newdata= raw_input("Enter your number: ")
    if newdata == "done": 
            break
    numberlist.append(newdata)
    if newdata != "":
        try:
            newdata=int(newdata)
            numberlist.append(newdata)
        except ValueError:
            print "Invalid input. Please enter a number"


findlargest()
findsmallest()
```

Comment: You're probably going to need to write some code...

Comment: while True:
    num= raw_input("Enter your number: ")
    if num == "done": 
        break
    print num
I wrote something like this but It doesn't work. Im not quite sure how to make it save every user input preferably to a set

Comment: You should put code into the question, preferably with what you inputting, desiring in terms of output/resulting conditions, and what you're actually ending up with. You know, the usual [MCVE]

Comment: kinda new here sorry for the inconvenience :( just updated my question I hope you can help explain

Comment: Well, you're going to get yelled at on here for that. Also...giyf, if you can't google the individual steps you want to do, and put them together, you're going to have problems, as well as frustrating people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, how about you take each user input, and...add it to a list?
Wow, I know, cutting edge. 
Then, I don't know, maybe do some operations on that list that find the `min` and `max`? 
Here's an example. If this is homework, you're better off rewriting for yourself. And if you're using Python 2.x, as your updated question indicates, you're going to have to modify what I'm giving you either way, because it is for Python 3

```
numberlist=[] #where we're storing our data
while True:
  print("Please enter a number, or 'Done'")
  newdata=input()
  if newdata == 'done' or newdata == 'Done' or newdata == 'DONE': #only gave options here because I typed the wrong case in while testing
    break #breaks the loop when done is entered
  numberlist.append(newdata) #adds the number entered to our list
print("List of numbers: "+str(numberlist))  
print("Min: "+min(numberlist)) 
print("Max: "+max(numberlist))
```

Comment: Hey I would like to say thank you so much! learnt about the new term numberlist and .appen(newdata)! this is my final code and it works fine. is there any comments you could pass on the code in terms of ways to maybe improve it? btw is there any way around the word limit for comments when pasting my code here?

Comment: There's a limit to comments, not so much for questions, as far as I know. And `numberlist` isn't a term, it's just what I chose to name the list. You can always edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works:

```
max = None
min = None
receiveInput = False
while True: 
    input = raw_input("Enter your number: ") 
    if input == "done": 
        if not receiveInput:
            print ("No numbers entered by user!")
        else:
            print ("Max: " + max)
            print ("Min: " + min)
        break 
    elif (max is None and min is None): 
        receiveInput = True
        max, min = input, input
    elif input > max:
        max = input
    elif input < min:
        min = input
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    list_value = []
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input()
        if user_input == "done":
            if list_value:
                sorted_array = sorted(list_value)
                print "successfully done \n largest number %s and smallest number %s" % (sorted_array[0], sorted_array[-1])
            break
        if user_input != '':
            try:
                user_value = int(user_input)
                list_value.append(user_value)
            except ValueError:
                print " Invalid input"
```

Comment: Hey how I would like to know how to integrate that try except condition in my code pls. I have edited my question to put in my final part of that section